# 'Anchor' component to the right of a row of components in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I want to display a list of components graphically across the screen in a row. I'm currently attempting to do this with the Grid Bag Layout manager. Additonally, the button to create a new component is just another component and is also included in the row. However, I want the button to always be the right most component. I've illustrated what I mean in the mock-ups below.[image: Example One]

The example above is before a component was added, and the example below is after.

[image: Example Two]

The only solution I can see is to manually remove and re-add the Creation button every time a component is added, but I'd like to find a more elegant way of fixing this than that.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use containers, one for all the new components and one for the button, using different layouts if you want to. Another solution might be to make the `gridx` position of of the button as far right as possible, and control the `gridx` positions of the other components as you add them

Comment: `The only solution I can see is to manually remove and re-add the Creation button every time a component is added` - you could just use a `FlowLayout`. Then you can use the Container.add(component, index) metod to add the component before the "Add New" button. The Container class will also tell you the number of components on the panel so you can use the appropriate index for the add.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing the component *before* I added a new one, and then just adding it again after the new component was added.